# how to access repeat purchase records for the next three months without self join?

Tags: sql, window-functions, presto, self-join

I have a table with customer transaction information, for example records for one customer (identified by customer_id) look like this:

| order_id | bk_date | booking_has_insurance_indicator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7/20 | 0 |
| 2 | 8/2 | 0 |
| 3 | 8/3 | 1 |
| 4 | 8/9 | 1 |
| 5 | 11/6 | 0 |
| 6 | 12/2 | 0 |
| 7 | 12/6 | 0 |
| 8 | 12/7 | 0 |

I'd like to find out for each customer, for each order_id, if there's repeat purchase within 90 days and how many of those, also if so, whether there's insurance attached. For example, for order_id = 1, there's three repeat purchase (order_id = 2,3,4) within 90 days and there exist orders with insurance (order_id = 3,4). Ideal output would look like

| order_id | bk_date | repeat_count | repeat_has_insurance_indicator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7/20 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 8/2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 8/3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 8/9 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 11/6 | 3 | 0 |
| 6 | 12/2 | 2 | 0 |
| 7 | 12/6 | 1 | 0 |
| 8 | 12/7 | 0 | 0 |

I'm aware that if I only want to access the next order record I can use LEAD window function without joining, but with question above, I could only think of self join to join each order_id to the ones with bk_date within 90 days. However, given the volume of the data with millions of customers, self join is also not an option due to memory limit. Could someone help me if there's a more efficient solution?

Comment: how sou you want to get a count, if no column indicates which customer has ordered anything or even what

Comment: "*self join is also not an option due to memory limit*" Could you show the self-join you tried and its `explain` please? It's possible it could be optimized. We'd also need to see the schema for your table *and its indexes*.

Comment: Could you explain why order_id 3 is a 2 and not a 1?

Comment: Also, what type is bk_date? And what type of SQL database are you using?

Comment: @Schwern Sorry I couldn't format the code so well above in comments but the idea is shown, and yes you are right order_id 3 is 1, my mistake. Hope this can clear things up a bit. The format for bk_date is DATE, and I'm using Presto. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Schwern 
`WITH base AS (
SELECT t1.*, 
t2.order_id AS repeat_order,
t2. repeat_has_insurance_indicator AS repeat_insurance
FROM table t1 --base table
LEFT JOIN table t2 --repeat table
ON t1.cust_id = t2.cust_id 
AND t2.bk_date BETWEEN date_add('day',1, t1.bk_date) AND date_add('day',91, t1.bk_date)
)
SELECT cust_id,order_id,COUNT(repeat_order) repeat_count, MAX(repeat_insurance) repeat_insurance
FROM base
GROUP BY cust_id,order_id`

Comment: @ds_somewhere 1) If you edit that into your answer, it will be much easier to read and for others to find 2) What does `explain analyze select ...` say? Also edit that info into your question. 3) Add the schema for the table to the question, please. Don't worry about the formatting, someone will clean it up.

Comment: We're going to need the `customer_id` column for this to make sense...